# How to ignore eslint in case of ^UNSAFE_ methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I just changed my `componentWillReceiveProps` to `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps`, but now my linter is throwing error:

`Identifier 'UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps' is not in camel case.eslint(camelcase)`

I tried using this in .eslintrc:

```
"camelcase": ["error", {"allow": ["^UNSAFE_"]}]
```

But, then it somehow broke, and the number of errors increased.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: What is your eslint version?

Comment: @0stone0 "eslint": "6.8.0"

Comment: Should be enough, could you show the result of the terminal command: `eslint -v`

Comment: `Command 'eslint' not found`. But I tried this: `yarn lint -v`, it shows: `yarn run v1.22.4
$ eslint -v
v6.8.0
Done in 0.32s.`

Comment: It's probably due to the eslint version. Try updating it though yarn: `yarn upgrade eslint`